# Python string json.loads error

Tags: python, string, json

What is the difrence between:

1. `s1 = '["a"]'`
2. `s2 = "['a']"`

When I do `json.loads`, I get following error for `s2` but `s1` is fine:

```py
>>> s1='["a2"]'
>>> s2="['a2']"
>>> json.loads(s1)
[u'a2']
>>> json.loads(s2)
 raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
 ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with `json`, but does the method require specific input string format?

Comment: Please correct your code and exception information - the exception should be `NameError`, because you define `s1` twice, but you define no `s2`. Please correct your code so it shows exactly what you saw.

Comment: @Ashish: Ok, I have corrected and formatted your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is **JSON uses double quotes (`"`) for quoting values**, not single ones (`'`).

Which means the exception is thrown because of invalid JSON:

- this is invalid JSON: `['a']`
- this is valid JSON: `["a"]`

Also the correct example is below, different than yours:

```py
>>> import json
>>> s1 = "['a']"
>>> s2 = '["a"]'
>>> json.loads(s1)
... some traceback removed ...
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
>>> json.loads(s2)
[u'a']
```

**EDIT**: I have updated the question with the correct output OP must have seen instead of what he/she posted (`json.loads('["a2"]')` was not throwing errors, `json.loads("['a2']")` was).

Answer (score 3):

json quotes are not interchangable like Python's are.

```
>>> import json
>>> print json.dumps("['a']")
"['a']"
>>> print json.dumps('["a"]')
"[\"a\"]"
```

In the second case the `"` need to be escaped